# Parsing log files with PowerShell switch regex

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse some domain controller auditing log files with PowerShell, by extracting just the bits of data that I need.  For example one of the logs files lists the domain trusts that exist within the domain, and I am trying to parse the list of domain trusts and export it to CSV.  Once I have got the initial script written, I intend to use it for several other auditing log files that I have by creating new PowerShell files and using different regular expressions within them.  My code works, but it only ever keeps the last value that is found rather than all values that are found.

In my code below, I get the Server name based on the name of the output of the log file (which I have omitted to keep the code I am showing simpler!).

```powershell
$DCDiagArray = @()
$Results = New-Object PSObject
$Dcdiag = Get-Content "D:\Temp\Logs\SERVER01_repadminshowtrust.txt"
$Dcdiag | ForEach-Object{
Switch -RegEx ($_)
{
"TRUSTED.+\s"   { $Trusted   = ($_ -Replace ".*TRUSTED.+\s: ").Trim() }
} 
If ($Trusted -ne $Null)
{
$Results | Add-Member -Name "ServerName" -Value $ServerName -Type NoteProperty -force
$Results | Add-Member -Name "DomTrust" -Value $Trusted -Type NoteProperty -force
$Trusted = $Null
} 
} 
$DCDiagArray += $Results
$DCDiagArray
```

Here is an example log file:

```
Repadmin: running command /showtrust against full DC localhost

Domain Trust Info:

    TRUSTED   : DC=domain1,DC=net
    TRUSTED   : DC=domain2,DC=net
```

What I should be expecting as an output is:

```
ServerName DomTrust
---------- --------
SERVER01   DC=domain1,DC=net
SERVER01   DC=domain2,DC=net
```

Instead all I get is:

```
ServerName DomTrust
---------- --------
SERVER01   DC=domain2,DC=net
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always add the last match to `$DCDiagArray`.

Change your code to:

```
$DCDiagArray = @()
$Dcdiag = Get-Content "server.txt"
$Dcdiag | ForEach-Object {
    Switch -RegEx ($_) {
        'TRUSTED.*\s' { 
            $Trusted = ($_ -Replace '.*TRUSTED.*\s: ').Trim() 
        }
    } 
    If ($Trusted -ne $Null) {
        $DCDiagArray += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName = "Undef"
            DomTrust = $Trusted
        }
        $Trusted = $Null
    } 
} 
$DCDiagArray
```

This returns (the servername is not set in my example):

```
ServerName DomTrust
---------- --------
Undef      DC=domain1,DC=net
Undef      DC=domain2,DC=net
```

As long as need no backwards compatibility to PowerShell 2 you can create a `CustomPSObject` via a hashtable in the form of:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
   Name = "Value"
}
```

Instead of `$Results = New-Object PSObject`.

Hope that helps

Comment: That resolved it, and everything is now working.  Thanks for your really valuable input :)

Answer (score 0):

`$DCDiagArray += $Results` needs to be moved into the Foreach-Object scriptblock:

```
$DCDiagArray = @()
$Dcdiag = Get-Content "D:\Temp\Logs\SERVER01_repadminshowtrust.txt"
$Dcdiag | ForEach-Object{
Switch -RegEx ($_)
{
"TRUSTED.+\s"   { $Trusted   = ($_ -Replace ".*TRUSTED.+\s: ").Trim() }
} 
If ($Trusted -ne $Null)
{
$Results = New-Object PSObject
$Results | Add-Member -Name "ServerName" -Value $ServerName -Type NoteProperty -force
$Results | Add-Member -Name "DomTrust" -Value $Trusted -Type NoteProperty -force
$DCDiagArray += $Results
$Trusted = $Null
} 
} 
$DCDiagArray
```

The problem is that the DomTrust property is getting overwritten as each object (`$_`) is processed. Once that Foreach-Object command **completes**, **then** you are adding it to your `$DCDiagArray` array. As a result, you only see the last value processed.